# MySQL Multi-table join on IDs

Tags: sql, mysql

Hey there, I need some help with some MYSQL Joins that I really don't have much idea how to achive, or if MySQL allows it.

I have a some tables setup, post_controller, post_text, post_photo, post_link.

post_controller has all the IDs and the post_text, post_photo, post_link tables can't have an entry unless post_controller has an id entry (foreign keys). I went for this aproach because I have different types of posts and I wanted to retrieve them regardless of the type of post it was so I just use the ID in the master table.

What I want to know is, how do I join the 3 tables with the master table to form a big array of all the posts, lets say I want posts 1 to 20 .. is it possible for me to join each type of post from each table like so.

```
post_contoller

id  userid   type   time
1      2      1     00:00
2      4      1     00:00
3      5      2     00:00
4      23     2     00:00
5      8      3     00:00
```

```
post_text

id   content       title
1   {sometext}   {sometext}
2   {sometext}   {sometext}
```

```
post_photo

id   content       hash
3   {sometext}   {somehash}
4   {sometext}   {somehash}
```

```
post_link

id   content      desc        link
5   {sometext}  {sometext}  {somelink}
```

End Resulting dataset.

```
post_photo

id  userid   type   time    content      title     desc      link        hash
1      2      1     00:00  {sometext}  {sometext}
2      4      1     00:00  {sometext}  {sometext}
3      5      2     00:00  {sometext}
4      23     2     00:00  {sometext}                                 {somehash}
5      8      3     00:00                        {sometext}{somelink}
```

Is this result set possible by joining the 3 tables with respect to the master IDs in the post_controller. If yes, please explain, if no please pose an alternate solution if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked out `UNION` or `LEFT JOIN`? either one of these should get you what you want in some form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
   SELECT c.*,
          IFNULL(IFNULL(p.content, t.content), l.content) AS content,
          t.title,
          l.desc,
          l.link,
          p.hash
     FROM post_contoller c
LEFT JOIN post_text t ON t.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN post_photo p ON p.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN post_link l ON l.id = c.id
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will try it out and see if it works out for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, with a slight modification to the SQL I was able to achieve the result I wanted.

Comment: Actually, i had to modify the 2nd line in the query. the "IFNULL(IFNULL(p.content, t.content), l.content) AS content," I had to remove the 1st IFNULL, but I guess that was only because I ran the test on linking 2 tables and the query that you posted is perfect only that its for 3 tables, although its still a bit unclear as to what exactly is the purpose of IFNULL over here, what purpose does it serve? I can take a guess that its for avoiding column duplication but why an IFNULL inside an IFNULL.

Comment: @Akay: because `IFNULL` accepts only 2 arguments. And you need to choose the one that not null from 3 columns.